# Upgrading gremlin breaks connection

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

With [gremlin javascript](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/tree/master/gremlin-javascript/src/main/javascript/gremlin-javascript) version `3.2.10` the following function connects to my Neptune cluster correctly:

```
export const initGremlinClient = () => {
  try {
    const dc = new DriverRemoteConnection(
      `ws://${process.env.NEPTUNE_ENDPOINT_URI}:${
        process.env.NEPTUNE_ENDPOINT_PORT
      }/gremlin`
    );
    const graph = new Graph();
    return {
      g: graph.traversal().withRemote(dc),
      closeGremlinConnection: () => dc.close()
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("[GREMLIN INIT ERROR]", error);
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

If I upgrade to version `^3.4.0` it throws the following error:

> "Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'reader' of undefined"

This is running in a Lambda function on NodeJS `8.10`. The docs don't seem to indicate anything new in this version, nor does AWS specify a compatibility issue with Neptune. Do I have this misconfigured?

EDIT: Adding stack trace

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'reader' of undefined",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "new Connection (/var/task/gremlinTest/node_modules/gremlin/lib/driver/connection.js:77:28)",
    "new Client (/var/task/gremlinTest/node_modules/gremlin/lib/driver/client.js:46:24)",
    "new DriverRemoteConnection (/var/task/gremlinTest/node_modules/gremlin/lib/driver/driver-remote-connection.js:53:20)",
    "exports.handler (/var/task/gremlinTest/index.js:6:14)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the original error?

Comment: @jorgebg I have added it.

Comment: If I pass in an empty object as the second arg to `new DriverRemoteConnection` it works.

Comment: Looks like it is this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TINKERPOP/issues/TINKERPOP-2130?filter=allopenissues

Comment: Yes, it is! thanks, you should post it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A patch was accepted for this recently and should land in 3.3.6 and 3.4.1 soon according to this [issue report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TINKERPOP/issues/TINKERPOP-2130?filter=allissues).