# Gremlin property math on a single vertex

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to perform some math on the properties of a Vertex. My solution works in the Gremlin console, but throws an error when run in JavaScript.

```
gremlin> g.addV("trip").property(single, "trackLength", 100).property(single, "travelDistance", 75).property(single, "carWeight", 10)

==>v[f8b42b9d-9053-2838-808d-ba14606b8390]

gremlin> g.V("f8b42b9d-9053-2838-808d-ba14606b8390").property(single, "carFactor", __.project("trackLength", "travelDistance", "carWeight").by("trackLength").by("travelDistance").by("carWeight").math("(trackLength - travelDistance) * carWeight")).valueMap()
```

I get the expected result when running in the console:

```
==>{trackLength=[100], travelDistance=[75], carWeight=[10], carFactor=[250.0]}
```

However when I run this in JS I get an error:

> TypeError: __.project(...).by(...).by(...).by(...).math is not a
>   function

Gremlin version `3.2.10`. I've tried upgrading to `^3.4.0` but am encountering a separate issue addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220750/upgrading-gremlin-breaks-connection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `math()` step was only [introduced](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/upgrade/#_added_code_math_code_step_for_scientific_traversal_computing) on 3.3.1, so if you're using 3.2.10, that's not going to work. Perhaps try 3.3.5 and see if `math()` works there.

Comment: May also be worth noting that for simple arithmetic such as add, multiply, subtract, that a fold() step can be used as in `g.V(1).sack(assign).by('some-property').sack(mult).by(constant(2)).sack()`